# Build error occurred ReferenceError: describe is not defined > During now.sh deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, next.js

I'm using **[now.sh](https://zeit.co/home)** to deploy my **[nextjs](https://nextjs.org/)** (React) app. And the build is failing due to this error:

`Build error occurred
ReferenceError: describe is not defined`

Not sure why this started happening, here is my `.babelrc`

```
{
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "compact": false,
      "presets": [
        "next/babel",
        "@zeit/next-typescript/babel"
      ],
      "plugins": [
        ["styled-components", {"ssr": true, "displayName": true}],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", {"legacy": true}]
      ]
    },
    "production": {
      "presets": [
        "next/babel",
        "@zeit/next-typescript/babel"
      ],
      "plugins": [
        ["styled-components", {"ssr": true, "displayName": true}],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", {"legacy": true}]
      ]
    },
    "test": {
      "compact": false,
      "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-typescript",
        ["next/babel", {"preset-env": { "modules": "commonjs" }}]
      ],
      "plugins": [
        ["styled-components", { "ssr": true, "displayName": true }],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
        ["babel-plugin-sass-vars"]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

package.json

```
"engines" : { 
    "node" : ">=8.10.0 <11.0.0" 
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development next -p 7777",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production next build",
    "start": "next -p 7777",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest --no-cache",
    "test-watch": "NODE_ENV=test jest --watch --no-cache",
    "coverage": "NODE_ENV=test jest --coverage",
    "update-snap": "NODE_ENV=test jest --updateSnapshot"
  },
```

Full log:

```
running "npm run now-build"
> moon.holdings@2.0.0 now-build /tmp/7418164
> next build
Creating an optimized production build ...
> Using external babel configuration
> Location: "/tmp/7418164/.babelrc"
> Build error occurred
ReferenceError: describe is not defined
    at Module.kAI8 (/tmp/7418164/.next/serverless/pages/__tests__/about.test.js:63996:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/tmp/7418164/.next/serverless/pages/__tests__/about.test.js:23:31)
    at module.exports.+3sd.exports.__esModule (/tmp/7418164/.next/serverless/pages/__tests__/about.test.js:91:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/7418164/.next/serverless/pages/__tests__/about.test.js:94:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
npm
ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

**The first test where the describe is used:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json'

import About from '../about.tsx'

describe('<About /> component', () => {
  describe('rendering', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<About />);
    it('should render a component matching the snapshot', () => {
      const tree = toJson(wrapper);
      expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
      expect(wrapper).toHaveLength(1);
      expect(wrapper.contains(<About/>));
    });
  });
});
```

**next.config**

```
module.exports = (phase, { defaultConfig }) => {
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.json$/,
          loader: 'json-loader'
        }
      ]
    }
    // Note: Nextjs provides webpack above so you should not `require` it
    // Perform customizations to webpack config
    // Important: return the modified config
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/\/__tests__\//))
    return config
  }

  // ✅ Put the require call here.
  const withTypescript = require('@zeit/next-typescript')
  const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-sass')

  // withCSS({target: 'serverless'})
  return withTypescript(withCSS({
    webpack(config, options) {
      return config
    }
  }))
}
```

Comment: In your last piece of code, where are you declaring `describe`?

Comment: Well `describe` is part of jest. I've never had to declare `describe` before in any app :(

Comment: Whoa strange, I just commented out the about.test.js code and it deployed fine ?? :( and I have other tests that also use `describe` so strange...

Comment: @LeonGaban how does your `next.config.js` look like (you can just post related code)

Comment: @Rikin just added my next.config!

Comment: @LeonGaban was this line added before the fix `config.plugins.push(new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/\/__tests__\//))` or is that the fix that run your build successfully

Comment: @Rikin ah I don't recall now... I just don't test the pages directory, are you able to in your NextJS app?

Comment: Just don't put any test files in the pages folder, because Next.js treats all files for routing which are in the pages folder.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I removed the tests that covered the `/pages` directory. NextJS used pages for routing. Not sure why that was causing the problem, ran coverage and looks like pages wasn't necessary to cover.

Hoping for a better answer from someone at the NextJS / Now.sh team, and I'll select that.

Comment: By default Next.js tries to treat all files in the `/pages` directory as pages for routing. You can customize the file extension of pages with https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-page-extensions so it will ignore files without that file extension. See my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/68718957/665224.

Comment: it works!  You need move `files.test.js` outside of pages directory

Comment: Works. Move your page tests to `__tests__` folder.

Answer (score 5):

Easy fix: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/3728#issuecomment-523789071

```js
pageExtensions: ['page.tsx']
```

Comment: Worked for me, as I had some .test.ts files on the /pages folder.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit: This answer is no longer needed for the new Next.js v13 app router which allows colocating other files with your pages in the `/app` directory.**

If you are looking to colocate non-page files with pages in the `/pages` directory, you can use [Custom Page Extensions](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-page-extensions) to force your pages to have a file extension of `.page.js`. Once that is setup, Next.js will ignore any files that don't have `.page` in the file extension.

`next.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  // Force .page prefix on page files (ex. index.page.tsx) so generated files can be included in /pages directory without Next.js throwing build errors
  pageExtensions: ['page.tsx', 'page.ts', 'page.jsx', 'page.js'],
}
```

<strike>I wrote some docs for this use case that have yet to be merged https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/22740.</strike> The docs link above now contains these changes.

The original Github issue where this was discovered is https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/3728#issuecomment-895568757.

Be aware that with the new Next.js v13 app router, this is no longer necessary as you can colocate other files with your pages in the router `/app` directory. If you've customized `pageExtensions`, this config will also apply to the app router and force you to rename pages in `/app` also. See https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/51478#issuecomment-1672314182 for more details about how `pageExtensions` affects the new app router file naming.

Answer (score 2):

An option that **allows the tests inside pages folder**:

change webpack settings direct in `next.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { webpack }) => {
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/\/__tests__\//))
    return config
  }
}
```

It is ignoring whatever `__tests__` folder found on the build process.

Comment: This no longer works for Next.js 11 `Error: Build optimization failed: found pages without a React Component as default export`.